# Convert xml to csv with php With this type of structure

Tags: php, xml, csv

I need to parse this xml structure to a csv separated data by columns (;) But it does not work, just create the header without the data

```html
    ----<ArticuloD>
    <codigo>10202</codigo>
    <familia>VARIOS</familia>
<subfamilia>LIBROS</subfamilia>
<subfamilia2>LIBROS</subfamilia2>
<subfamilia3>LIBROS</subfamilia3>
<subfamilia4>LIBROS</subfamilia4>
<ean>9788425351501</ean><talla>ST</talla>
    ----</ArticuloD>
    ---<ArticuloD>
```

My php code:

```html
<?php


    $file='ListaArticulosD-507.xml';


    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
        $f = fopen('user.csv', 'w');
        // array to hold the field names
        $headers = array(); 
        // loop through the first set of fields to get names
       foreach ($xml->ArticulosD->ArticuloD->children() as $field) {  
            // put the field name into array
            $headers[] = $field->getName(); 
        }
        // print headers to CSV
        fputcsv($f, $headers, ';', '"');

        foreach ($xml->ArticuloD->children() as $users) {
            fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($users), ';', '"');
        }
        fclose($f);
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: Is `----` part of your XML?

Comment: "----" nooo sorry I put it so that the structure is visible<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResultadoListaArticulosD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.com/apps/articulos/Ficheros.asmx">
  <estado>true</estado>
  <ArticulosD>
    <ArticuloD>
      <codigo>10202</codigo>
      <familia>VARIOS</familia>
      <subfamilia>LIBROS</subfamilia>
      <subfamilia2>LIBROS</subfamilia2>
      <subfamilia3>LIBROS</subfamilia3>
      <subfamilia4>LIBROS</subfamilia4>
      <ean>9788425351501</ean>

Answer (score 1):

Your last `foreach` loop is going too far down into the structure, if you change it to...

```
foreach ($xml->ArticuloD as $users) {
```

Then the output I get is

```
codigo;familia;subfamilia;subfamilia2;subfamilia3;subfamilia4;ean;talla
10202;VARIOS;LIBROS;LIBROS;LIBROS;LIBROS;9788425351501;ST
```

Sometimes using `print_r()` when your fetching data like this can give you a hint as to what your working with at each point.  Just remember to take them out before delivering any code!